# Javascript “Cannot read property 'length' of undefined” when checking a variable's length

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please tell me what is the problem in this code.

```
let walletAddress = request.body.walletAddress;

if (walletAddress.length < 34) {
    return response.status(400).json({
        walletAddress: 'Invalid Wallet Address'
    });
}
```

Comment: `walletAddress` is undefined

Comment: Check `request.body` instead.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough code include or enough evidence of debugging and data form debugging to know for sure what is going on.

The very first thing you would do is do a:

```
console.log(req.body)
```

at the beginning of your request handler and see what it contains.  This is basic debugging that you should do before you come here.  It appears there is apparently no `walletAddress` property in `req.body`.

Then you have to figure out why that is.  Either you aren't sending the right kind of request from Postman (either it's not a POST or it doesn't have the right data with it or something else is wrong with the request) or you don't have the body-parser middleware installed to read and parse the body to actually fill in the properties on `req.body` from the POST data.

For help with either of these, show us the rest of your server set up code so we can see where body-parser middleware is or isn't installed  and what your request handler looks like.  And, show us the exact request you're sending from Postman.